# Differences between using Lambda Expressions and without using it?

Tags: java, lambda

Could someone explain my the differences between methods using lambda expressions and without using it? 
On the example:

```
 Function<Double, Double> function;

public void methodCounting() {
        this.function = x -> x = x + 2;
}  

 public double methodCounting(double x) {
             x = x + 2;
            return x;
    }
```

What do we gain?

Comment: @Eran I miss typed type of the second function.

Comment: With lambda expressions you don't gain anything except, optimized performance and shorter code. But in your case, both of your examples are identical

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach so everything is about the performance and shorter code ?

Comment: You can do everything without lambda expressions. But they are really useful and you will code faster with them.

Comment: OK, Thanks ! I will use them now consciously.

Answer (score 0):

Your second method accepts a double number and returns that number + 2.

Your first method defines a `Function` that accepts a `Double` number and returns a `Double` whose value is the original + 2. It doesn't, however, evaluate that `Function`.

In order to produce the output of the second method, you could later pass a value to that `Function` and evaluate it :

```
Double d = function.apply(x); // will assign x+2 to d
```

would behave similarly to

```
double d = methodCounting(x);
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that after 'apply' method I'll assign this value. I want to know only that what we will get if we using lambda's

Answer (score 0):

- Lambda is new feature added in java 8 only for optimum performance and shorter code.
- Java 8 provide support for lambda expressions only with functional interfaces.
- Any Interface with single abstract method is called Functional Interface.
- Functional Interface is also a new feature introduced in Java 8.
- lambda expressions is implicitly generate function objects in a "more convenient way" please ref. above code.